# Passing concatenated datetime params via openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a local stored procedure that calls another on a remote linked server. The problem is that my local stored proc uses `openquery` to call the remote stored proc and pass two `DATETIME` parameters.

The only way I can successfully call the remote stored proc is to concatenate the query and its parameters and then use `sp_executesql` - note RPC is NOT enabled on the remote server, which only limits the successful methods.

The problem is that concatenating the datetimes in order to pass them as variables is causing problems within the remote proc, which expects `datetime` params not `nvarchar`, which is what the concatenation is doing.

Is there any way around this? The last resort would be to modify the remote proc and have it accept `nvarchar` and then immediately convert them to `datetime`. This is not a viable approach since the remote procs are in use within other systems.

**The local SP**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAttendanceReport]
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @paramDef nvarchar(500) = N'@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime',
    @query nvarchar(500) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    set @query = N'select * from OPENQUERY([REMOTE-SRV], ''EXEC db.dbo.ReportAttendance_sp ' + convert(nvarchar(30), @StartDate, 112) + ',' + convert(nvarchar(30), @EndDate, 112) + ''')'
    exec sp_executesql @query, @paramDef, @StartDate, @EndDate
END
```

**The remote SP**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportAttendance_sp] 
    @VenueID int = null,
    @StartDate datetime = null,
    @EndDate datetime = null,
    @AttendanceStatusID int = null
AS
BEGIN
...
```

I pass the following params:

```
@StartDate = N'2011-01-01',
@EndDate = N'2012-01-01'
```

Executing the SP I get the error from the remote SP:

> Error converting data type int to datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass those concatenated params as if they were strings. Currently, they look like ints, as the error message implies - you need to double-up single quotes to embed them as string delimiters, and then *again* because they're inside dynamic SQL. Also, there is no reason to use NVARCHAR for those literals specifically, nor do you need 30 characters to represent style 112. You just need to use CHAR(8). Finally, you don't need to pass the parameters to `sp_executesql` if you're not actually using any of them as strongly typed parameters (which I don't think you can in combination with OPENQUERY under dynamic SQL). So:

```
SET @query = N'SELECT * from OPENQUERY([REMOTE-SRV], 
  ''EXEC db.dbo.ReportAttendance_sp ''''' + convert(char(8), @StartDate, 112) 
      + ''''',''''' + convert(char(8), @EndDate, 112) + ''''';'');';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

(Of course, you really should explicitly name those parameters, which at least protects you from someone changing the interface later, e.g. by adding a parameter to the beginning of the param list.)

However, that begs the question, why not just fix the RPC problem and then:

```
EXEC [REMOTE-SRV].db.dbo.ReportAttendance_sp @StartDate, @EndDate;
```

Comment: Why does the IT department get to dictate whether you can execute stored procedures across linked servers, which seems to be your actual business requirement here?

Comment: I didn't realise enabling RPC was as trivial as setting it to true under properties. How simple things will be from now on :)